# the_content(); erroneously closing off previous opening before it

Tags: permalinks, post-thumbnails, the-content, iframe

I have a custom loop that is displaying a "most popular" posts section. It first creates a linked container (`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> ... </a>`), and then stores data from the current post in the loop within that container.

If the post has a thumbnail, it displays the image (`if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); }`). Otherwise, it executes `the_content();` in the `else { }` part, wherein it can grab an iframe and display that instead.

For some reason, if it goes into the `else { }` part, it will close the opening `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">` statement with a closing `</a>` tag first. This results in `<div class="most-popular-article"></div>` and its contents coming *after* the `<a></a>` container rather than inside of it.

Does anyone know what exactly is happening here, or how to prevent it from happening?

```
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="most-popular-article">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
                }
                else {
                the_content();
                } ?>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </a>
```

Comment: Does the posts content have links in it? You can’t have links inside links.

Comment: The post is not composed with any links in it, but it renders with the permalink in the `<div class="most-popular-article"></div>`, which I'm guessing gets pulled out from `the_content();`

Comment: There's most likely a problem with the iframe part. You shouldn't render an iframe inside an anchor. Try putting some normal text as content, and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_content() is probably rendering a link ( or maybe your browser may be auto formatting one ).

You can test if this is so by instead of using the_content();

using

```
// Get the Content of the post 
$postContent = get_the_content();
// Escape all the HTML
$postContent =  htmlentities($postContent);
// Print it to screen and verify if any links are inside.
print_r($postContent);
```

if you have links in the content or expect them try simply replacing them like

```
// Get the Content of the post 
$postContent = get_the_content();
// some simple regex 
$postContent = preg_replace('/<a.+?>/','<strike>',$postContent);
// some more simple regex 
$postContent = preg_replace('/<\/a>/','</strike>',$postContent);
echo $postContent;
```

The above code will render all the links as strike through text you could replace this with underlines or even with a span that with the clever use of capture groups could be used to bind click events to said spans and you could still have functional links.